# How to clarify what you mean by "Standard Time" in relation to time zones?

Tags: ambiguity, time

It seems like the term "Standard Time" in the context of describing a time zone is ambiguous.  For example "Pacific Standard Time" could either mean:

- As distinct from "Pacific Daylight Time", meaning **8 hours** behind Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) and no other number.

**or**

- As distinct from other time zones such as "Eastern Time", meaning either **7 or 8 hours** behind GMT, depending on the season, so either "Standard Time" or "Daylight Time".

I don't want to ever use the term "Pacific Standard Time", at least not on its own.  I am looking for alternative terminology that is not ambiguous.

Comment: Both bullets look right, but only the first matches your opening question.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, I edited for clarity.  I don't want to ever use the ambiguous term "Pacific Standard Time", at least on its own.  I am looking for alternatives to that term.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for.  Pacific, in this context means an are consisting of parts of western Canada, US, and Mexico.  Standard, in this context, means "not daylight savings time". If you don't care about whether it's daylight savings or not, just say "Pacific Time"

Comment: One thing that needs to be understood is that at one time every city in the US had their own "time zone" -- nothing was standardized.  This drove the railroads crazy (how do you publish a schedule if there's no standard time reference?) so they settled on a "railroad time" standard where all the railroads would use the same clock.  This became "standard time" even before governments stepped in to regulate things.

Comment: @Kevin: 'If you don't care about whether it's daylight savings or not, just say "Pacific Time"' seems to be exactly what the OP is looking for. Would you consider posting some version of it as an answer?

Comment: At precisely the same instant, the first two of these are in Mountain Time and the third is in Pacific Time: `#1: In Denver, it is now 2020-09-10 16:24:09 -0600 (MDT).
#2: In Phoenix, it is now 2020-09-10 15:24:09 -0700 (MST).
#3: In Los Angeles, it is now 2020-09-10 15:24:09 -0700 (PDT)`. **Which of those three  are the *‘same time’* as each other?**  The two in Mountain Time, even though one has 16:24:09 and the other has 15:24:09?  The two that think it’s 15:24:09 even though one is in MST and the other in PDT? All three of them? None of them? **Still** think ‘Standard’ is dispensable⁈ 

Comment: It just occurred to me that in the UK, they use the term "summer time".  I'm not sure what they use during the winter, whether they say "winter time" or "standard time".  But I don't think "summer time" is well understood in the US.

Comment: @BlueWhale Well, the UK for historical reasons uses "Greenwich Mean Time" as the formal name for the "standard time" and "British Summer Time" as the formal name for the "daylight savings time". I don't think mixing any of those terms in there would help, though.

Comment: Related Saving: [Daylight Savings Time - “Saving” or “Savings”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379045/daylight-savings-time-saving-or-savings)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, GMT is not the same as British Standard Time. They both just happen to currently share the same offset of zero.  Unlike British Standard Time, GMT is used throughout the year and throughout the world.  If Britain decided to use "summer time" (offset +1) all year (a realistic prospect), GMT would not change from offset zero.

Comment: @BlueWhale British Standard Time? That is not an often mentioned name, but as far as I understand that is the name of a time zone used in an experiment that ran between 1968 and 1971 with all-year +1 offset. The current actively used time zones in the UK are British Summer Time (+1) and Greenwich Mean Time (+0). As for what a potential future change in legislation might do, I don't think that has any real bearing on the current situation. https://www.timeanddate.com/time/uk/time-zone-background.html seems to have a good summary.

Comment: @BlueWhale Is the concern raised actually based on confusing GMT with UTC? (speculation on my part, but that would seem to explain it)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, so there is no simple term for "the time currently in use in Britain", analogous to "Pacific Time" which means whichever of "Pacific Daylight Time" or "Pacific Standard Time" is currently in use?

Comment: @BlueWhale I suppose phrases like "UK time", "London time", etc would have to do. The concept of "Standard Time" refers the first of the two options in your question (only that timezone offsets are relative to UTC, not GMT), it *does not* have the meaning of the second option.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, isn't UTC the same as GMT?

Answer (score 5):

The phrase *Pacific Standard Time (PST)* is not ambiguous **when used correctly**: it stands for UTC-8 (or GMT-8), i.e. for the first of the two alternatives in the question.

The term for the second of the two alternatives in the question is *Pacific Time (PT)*, or *the time in the Pacific Time Zone*. One can also say 'the local time', if the context makes it clear what the location is, or something like 'when it's five o'clock in Los Angeles'. All of them unambiguously stand for whichever of PST or PDT is observed on the relevant day.

Now, it is true that people sometimes use *PST* when they, in fact, mean PT, probably in a misguided attempt to sound more official. That mistake is sufficiently widespread that the phrase may occasionally be confusing in practice, so it is understandable that the OP is reluctant to use it. Fortunately, the phrase is easy to avoid, as in day-to-day life, one very rarely needs it, because one almost never refers to PST for the part of the year in which it is not actually observed (and for the part of the year in which it is observed, there is no difference between it and PT).

Comment: OK, so I can use "Pacific Time" (or PT) in the way you described.  But what term can I use for what you described as "rarely used", e.g. UTC-8?  For example, suppose there is some automated device, that cannot be changed, and I want to say that it transmits data at 2pm PST, throughout the year, and I don't want to use the term PST because it is sometimes misused, and I want to be unambiguous? In other words, I want a term that means UTC-8, without using that highly technical term?

Comment: *UTC-8* is a somewhat technical term, but **not** a **highly** technical term; chances are that the people who need to understand the functioning of the device you are describing will know what it means. Even more people will readily understand *GMT-8*.

Comment: Alternatively, I could say "the device transmits daily at 10pm GMT"

Comment: Or.... 2pm Standard Time, 3pm Daylight Time.

Answer (score 2):

While you, your organization, or localized figures of speech are free to establish whatever convention you care to, there exists an international voluntary standards organization that has addressed this question in a published standard, [ISO-8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html)

> This ISO standard helps remove doubts that can result from the various day–date conventions, cultures and time zones that impact a global operation. It gives a way of presenting dates and times that is clearly defined and understandable to both people and machines.

I understand the present conventional meaning of "Pacific Standard Time" as the time in certain US Pacific states when daylight savings time is not in effect.
The unambiguous way to describe this is by an offset to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), rendered as "UTC-08:00".  While the actual standard is behind a paywall, the functional information is reproduced on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC%E2%88%9208:00,_U).

Comment: @choster fair enough, because the issue is ambiguity of "daylight savings" time. Rephrased

Comment: In other words (to answer the OP directly), the second of the two ways of using *PST* that the question is about is simply a mistake, and the phrase is thus not ambiguous **when used correctly**. The mistake is, however, not all that rare, which is why the phrase can sometimes cause confusion.

Comment: OK but an offset is not generally understood and thus impractical.  I want 2 unambiguous terms, 1 for each of the bullet points in my question.

Comment: @BlueWhale Pacific Daylight Time (PDT) and Pacific Standard Time (PST) are the two formal names, which *are* unambiguous in their definition. If we give up on the term PST because people occasionally use it incorrectly, that only makes it more complicated to communicate what is what.